# Activity is sometimes closed on ProgressDialog dismiss

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have an `Activity` with a tabbed UI in which I load 3 fragments through a `ViewPagerAdapter`.
1 fragment (called C) is a simple `PreferenceFragment`, 1 (B) is only a `TextView` the last one (A) extends `Fragment` and I use it to show a `ListView` containing all the installed packages on the devices.

When the user open the app, an `AsyncTask` in Fragment A loads the packages and it prepares the adapter to pass to the `ListView`. Moreover, I use a ProgressDialog in the AsyncTask to inform the users that the list is almost ready.

I leave you with some code:

Inner AsyncTask in fragment C:

```
private class AppListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<Map<String, Object>>> {

    Context context;

    public AppListTask(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                AppListTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Map<String, Object>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        // get list of apps
        progressDialog.setMax(list.size());
        int nApps = 1;
        for(ResolveInfo info : list) {
            //work on info
            nApps++;
            publishProgress(nApps);
        }
        //return
     }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, Object>> items) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing() && !((Activity) context).isDestroyed()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        }
        //set adapter on list view
    }
}
```

and I execute it from `onActivityReady` in Fragment C

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

...


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (listAdapter == null || listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
        new AppListTask(getActivity()).execute();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

...
```

The problem is that on Note4 it works perfectly while on galaxy S5 happens something strange.

If I open the app the first time, as soon as the ProgressDialog is dismissed (in `onPostExecute`), the app is automatically closed without exceptions. At the second or third launch instead it works good.
If I do not use the ProgressDialog at all, it works good on first launch.

I also tried to use the ProgressDialog as `setCancelable(false)` but nothing changes.

Comment: Any error in logcat?

Comment: Try debugging. See what you get.